# unity freeze and crash when change scene. Any idea?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When I try to change the scene it freezes, then crashes. But after a while I tried again to open the app, and it worked. Any idea why?

I've already unchecked split application binary. I also tried to open an empty scene and it worked perfectly fine. Could it have anything to do with my object in the scene?
This happens only on Android, it worked well in unity editor.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons. Without code or project settings we can only guess what caused crash. When debugging on Android, it is good to use [logcat](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat.html) from which you can read what caused the crash.

How to add logcat to project:

1. In Unity editor: Window - Package Manager - Android Logcat - Install
2. Build and run your project
3. You will find what caused the crash in logs

This way you can identify most errors and not just this specific one.